# need to calculate 2 input fields and display in 3rd

Tags: javascript, html

I want to multiply the quantity by price and 'display' in total. Total needs to be named "amount" in order to transfer the total cost to the gateway. As you can see I'm trying to create a get around to be able to use quantity.

All information here is for test purposes so isn't personal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function totalprice() {
    var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var price = 219999;
    var total = (qty * price);
    document.getElementById("tot").value = total;
}
</script>

<form action="https://gateway.charityclear.com/hosted/" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="merchantID" value="0000992">
<input type="hidden" name="countryCode" value="826"> 
<input type="hidden" name="currencyCode" value="826">  
<table>
<tr>
<td>Full Name </td><td><input type="text" name="customerName" value=></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Full Shipping Address <br>(including Country)<br>(must be same as billing     address)</td><td><textarea rows="4" name="customerAddress" value=></textarea></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Post Code </td><td><input type="text" name="customerPostCode" value=></td>          </tr>
<tr>
<td>Email Address </td><td><input type="text" name="customerEmail" value=></td> </tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone Number <br>(required for delivery)</td><td><input type="text" name="customerPhone" value=></td></tr>

<input type="hidden" name="redirectURL" value="http://www.UKRobstep.com/order- successful.html">
<tr><td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="Colour">Colour</td>
<td>
<select name="orderRef">
<option value="Select a Colour">Select a Colour
<option value=" Robin M1 in Black">Black
<option value=" Robin M1 in White "> White
<option value=" Robin M1 in Red"> Red
<option value=" Robin M1 in Yellow ">Yellow
<option value=" Robin M1 in Silver/Grey "> Silver/Grey
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>

Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="field"  value="1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Price Per Unit</td><td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="field" value="£2199.99" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="tot" class="field" value=""/>
</td></tr>

</table>
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/9/8/2/8/9828047/5792561_orig.png" BORDER="0" ALT="Pay Now" > 
</form>
```

I hope someone can help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it needs to be named "amount" why not name it "amount?"

Answer (score 0):

use `parseInt();`

**Example**

```
function totalprice()
{
    var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var price = 219999;
    var total = (parseInt(qty) * price);
    -------------^^^^^^^^^--------------
    document.getElementById("tot").value = total;
}
```

Comment: No, not at all. The `*` operator will coerce both operands into `Number`s and perform the calculation. The result will be a number or `NaN`

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ2Gb/7/) in this demo i used jQuery to call function..this is just to show you that its working.

Comment: And it works **exactly** the same if you **don't** include the `parseInt` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying a way to get value after user enters quantity? I'm not sure what you mean by "get around".  Here's a way of returning value after enter key is pressed.

```
<script>
 function totalprice() {
    var KeyID = event.keyCode;
    if(KeyID == 13){
      var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
      var price = 219999;
      var total = (qty * price);
      document.getElementById("tot").value = total;
             alert(total);
  }
  else{
  }
}

</script>


 <form action="https://gateway.charityclear.com/hosted/" method="post"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="merchantID" value="0000992">

 <input type="hidden" name="countryCode" value="826"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="currencyCode" value="826">  
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>Full Name </td><td><input type="text" name="customerName" value=></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Full Shipping Address <br>(including Country)<br>(must be same as billing      
 address)</td><td><textarea rows="4" name="customerAddress" value=></textarea></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Post Code </td><td><input type="text" name="customerPostCode" value=></td>          
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Email Address </td><td><input type="text" name="customerEmail" value=></td> </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Phone Number <br>(required for delivery)</td><td><input type="text" 
name="customerPhone" value=></td></tr>

 <input type="hidden" name="redirectURL" value="http://www.UKRobstep.com/order- 
successful.html">
 <tr><td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="Colour">Colour</td>
 <td>
 <select name="orderRef">
 <option value="Select a Colour">Select a Colour
 <option value=" Robin M1 in Black">Black
 <option value=" Robin M1 in White "> White
 <option value=" Robin M1 in Red"> Red
 <option value=" Robin M1 in Yellow ">Yellow
 <option value=" Robin M1 in Silver/Grey "> Silver/Grey
 </select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>

 Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="field"    
value="1" onkeydown="return totalprice(this, event);"  /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Price Per Unit</td><td><input type="text" name="price" id="price"  
class="field" value="£2199.99" readonly="readonly"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="tot" class="field" value=""/>
</td></tr>

 </table><INPUT TYPE="image"    
SRC="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/9/8/2/8/9828047/5792561_orig.png" BORDER="0" 
ALT="Pay    Now" > </form>
```